# Switch-case in c: continue to 'default' from within another case

Tags: c, switch-statement

Is there a way to start handling a case, and in the **middle** (not end) of it to move on to run the 'default'. I saw that I can drop the 'break', but it continues to the next cases just after ending the whole current case. 
Example:

```
switch( X ) 
{
    case 'A':
        // Start this code
        if (expression){
            // Go to execute 'default'
        }
        // Don't run this if the expression is true
    case 'B':
            // code..
    default :
            // code..
}
```

(Looking for a solution other than making the 'default' a function and calling it from the case)

Comment: No solution, just use the function! You can always use a label and `goto`, but I think it will hurt the logic very much and make the code difficult to understand.

Comment: you may be able to insert a label anywhere in your switch and `goto label;` in your `if` clause ?

Comment: @Magix - Yes, that is a good solution. For the others up here - you are right about the logic issues, the thing is I need to make the minimum changes to the code, and code duplication / creating a function, are not good for this case.

Comment: @Yigal Would If statements work? It would require less code in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a label:

```
goto default2;
```

if you put a:

```
default2:
```

next to the default

Answer (score 1):

The `case` statements do not have to be in sequence.

```
switch( X ) 
{
    case 'B':
        // code..
        break;
    case 'A':
        // code..
        if (!expression){
            // code
            break;
        }
        // code..
        // Fall thru
    default :
        // code..
}
```

This removes the ugly `goto`

Comment: Yes but this assumes that case A is the only one that has the if. The question would be if there are a number of cases.

Comment: This code above falls thru and executes case B if the expression is false as well as executing case B from the switch. It also appears that default is treated as a case and as the fall through from case A or B. THis seems to mean that the switch would not work.as well as ifs.

Comment: @sabbahillel *This code above falls thru and executes case B if the expression is false*  Could you explain that?  I see the (current) code for X equal to either A or B as "if X is B, do B then break; if X is A do A then if !expression break else fall through to default".  I see no way to fall through from B.

Comment: @sabbahillel if more cases need `default` the use of `goto` can still be avoided by restructuring the code. `case 'A': case 'Z':` and then distinguish these.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to start handling a case, and in the middle (not end) of it to move on to run the 'default'.

There *is* a way, as described in geocar's correct and succinct answer. But you should also consider whether you *should* use a `goto` to modify the flow of execution through a `switch` statement. It's not something that most people would expect to see, and there's a lot to be said for avoiding code that works in surprising ways. **If you decide to do what you're proposing, include a comment that explains what's going on and why you did it this way.**

Comment: Agree. Take a look in my comment to the question. Thanks

Comment: *minimum changes* doesn't necessarily mean the smallest difference in the text. Adding a `goto` to a `switch` case generally isn't a great way to fix something. Sometimes you have to do what you have to do, but when you have to do it it's always a good idea to leave some explanation of *what* you did and *why* you had to do it. I'm really not trying to tell you what to do, just encouraging you and others who will read your question in the future to be as transparent as possible when you do strange things.

Comment: I understood that was the reason. I think your answer is important

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that it would be better to handle this with a flag check inside case B and let the fall throughwork properly. Any other cases that would want to avoid the default would go before case A and have a break.

Looking at the code in the question, it appears that you want to have both case A fall into case B (and check the expression) and then have case B fall through into the default so that the default is executed in all cases. It also appears that you do not want to change the switch to move the default outside the switch (minimal changes).

```
int myflag = FALSE;
switch( X ) 
{
  case 'A':
  {
    // Start this code
    if (expression){
        myflag = TRUE;
        // Now the fall through would go to default
    }
  }
    // Don't run this if the expression is true
  case 'B':
    {
        if (! myflag) {
          // code..
        }
    }
  default :
        // code..
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best you can do (since you don't want the default code in a function) is to put the default code after the switch, and set a flag when you want the default code to run.

```
int runDefault = false;

switch( X ) 
{
    case 'A':
        // Start this code
        if (expression){
            runDefault = true;
            break;
        }
        // This code doesn't run this if the expression is true
        break;

    case 'B':
        // code..
        break;

    default :
        runDefault = true;
        break;
}

if ( runDefault )
{
    // default code goes here
}
```